# Subir una imagen o archivo con python en selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Buenas tengo un problema, estoy intentando subir una imagen pero no me deja, he probado con send_keys y con otros formas y no hay manera, si me puedes ayudar, al clickar en lo que sale en la imagen sale el explorador de archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]